# Why is the term "unit of work" so important and why does JDBC AutoCommit violate this pattern?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, unit-of-work, jdbctemplate

I am study how Spring handle transaction and I can't give a precise answer to the following question founded on the study material:

> Why is the term "unit of work" so important and why does JDBC
>   AutoCommit violate this pattern?

So, I know that the **unit of work** is a desing pattern that **maintains a list of objects affected by a business transaction and coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of concurrency problems**.

So I know that with Spring **JdbcTemplate** I can have something like this:

```
try {
    conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    …
    conn.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    conn.rollback();
    ...
}
```

where **conn.setAutoCommit(false);** is a **programmatic transaction demarcation** (because in this case I am programmatically declaring my transaction that is all that happens between the previous operation and the final commit operation).

So, from what I understand (but it can be wrong). If instead false I have:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

each individual SQL statement between this statment and the final commit is is treated as a transaction and is automatically committed right after it is executed. So, in this way, I will have n committed SQL statment and it is contrary to the logic of unit of works that **maintains a list of objects affected by a business transaction and coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of concurrency problems**.

Is it reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your explanation is correct but shows little understanding. The important question is: Why is it bad when each SQL is committed to the database as soon as possible?

To answer this, you need to come up with a scenario where you change two objects. The change must be related somehow by business rules. Transferring money from one bank account to the next is a common example here. I suggest that you write down all necessary SQL statements and then play through different scenarios like:

- Does the order of statements matter?
- What happens when not all statements are executed?

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is fairly sound on this.

Answer (score 1):

Unit of Work design pattern does two important things: first it maintains in-memory updates and second it sends these in-memory updates as one transaction to the database.

It is important because you can take control over the business rules represented by the unit work and applies the ACID principles

- **Atomic** -Each unit of work is an all-or-nothing operation.
- **Consistent** - Database integrity constraints are never violated
- **Isolated** - Isolating transactions from each other
- **Durable** - Committed changes are permanent

When the JDBC AutoCommit is active then you are breaking the ACID principle.